# Why is my flag on this comment as being unconstructive rejected when it basically a broken link only comment?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, comment-flags

I flagged a comment as not constructive because the comment basically says go checkout my answer .... and the link goes no where because that persons answer has long been deleted... if you open the link in a new tab you'll see it takes you to the same page we started on. Yet my comment was marked not helpful.

this points out two questions:  why is this a constructive comment if it simple has a link that just goes back to the same page.( and not his suggested answer)

the answer link is : [GNU make: prepend a recursively expanded variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35516996/gnu-make-prepend-a-recursively-expanded-variable/36863261#36863261)

The comment was by 'pryftan' and is the last comment which says

> Hacky solution, but there is no native GNU make feature for such
>   problem If you mean prepend to a variable that's not true (at least
>   it's not now in 2019). See my answer on this:
>   stackoverflow.com/a/58221246/9205647 - far cleaner and nicer in my
>   mind though it's always a wonderful feeling when you come up with a
>   hack to solve a problem the more clever the better. – Pryftan Oct 3
>   '19 at 14:32

Here's my flag which didn't use the word literal and actually was as correct as I could make it at the time:

> GNU make: prepend a recursively expanded variable? answered Apr 26 '16
>   at 11:12 by Kuchara it no longer links to an answer – UpAndAdam Feb 26
>   at 16:47   declined

the second point is that in the comment reviews how do you actually identify the comment that was marked not helpful? It seems very unclear and I knew it, but otherwise its completely unclear what is being talked about. I have some cases where I flagged multiple comments on a given answer..  That's a separate point for a proposal perhaps based upon feedback though

Comment: How does that link *"go literally nowhere"*? For those with >=10K rep it takes us to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58221246/2029983) and for those with less, it still takes them to the question [GNU make: prepend a recursively expanded variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35516996/2029983). it's not a broken link at all.

Comment: right... most users have less 10k rep and can't see his deleted answer... so how is that useful to the general population.   Which means his answer is link only for the poster and anyone involved in the question. how is that helpful?    10k rep + is like what less than 1% of the site?

Comment: as in, I can only see two answers on the page and neither is his.  the person he's commenting to has sub thousand rep and NO way of seeing it... so again how is this constructive to 99% of the users on the site?

Comment: It seems like you are taking the word nowhere a little too literally.

Comment: Helpful and and "goes literally nowhere" aren't  the same thing though. (way less than 1% of the site have 10K rep though, it's closer to 0.2% according to the [leader board](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow)).

Comment: its not a dilemma between helpful and literally nowhere.. its a difference of literally nowhere and circularly adding no value.  How is his comment helpful to anyone but a 10k plus user? such as THE OP

Comment: I think the problem Lamu points out is that you are using the word "literally" not in a literal sense.

Comment: you only help my point by pointing out its less than 1% thanks... so for 99.98% of the people on the site his link goes effectively no where and his entire comment is basically akin to : go see me great answer at <link to the page were on with no such answer >

Comment: If one discounts 1 rep users (throwaway account and the like), I think 10k users are around 8% of the site. Not saying that's an argument for keeping or deleting the comment.

Comment: fine, in my comment on the flag i shouldn't have said 'literally'... but there is still onus on the mod to look at what the link does.

Comment: You can argue the minutia of the wordings all you like; you have yet to dispute how my flagging of that comment as unhelpful is incorrect.   No one has presented it as being accessible to more than 8% of the site, and no one has presented how any of the conversation participants benefit from it...  So who is the comment helpful for?

the wording of my comment is additional help, it doesn't make my flag incorrect.. its like saying I only want to spend 2 secs on reviewing it, and it went somewhere, how long do you think I want to type out its a circular link? lol

Comment: I'm not familiar with the technology, but it seems like there's still some useful information in the comment despite the broken link? Or maybe the moderator who rejected it just didn't realize it was broken.

Comment: I pasted the comment exactly, I pasted a link to the answer.  The only place I said literally was in my flag comment where I think I said "this link goes literally nowhere" perhaps I'll concede that but you have all spent more time examining my wording than it would have taken to LOOK AT THE PAGE and see the link was useless

Comment: @UpAndAdam but my point is that the link *doesn't* take you "literally nowhere"; you don't get a 404, it's not broken. it';s not literally no where at all; it's the complete opposite. A mod reading the flag may well have checked the link, saw it worked, and declined because the statement wasn't true. If the flag had said "this goes to an answer the OP has since deleted", the outcome may well have been different.

Comment: the two remaining answers don't have any relationship to the comments being helpful or not @BSMP

Comment: @Lamu I conceded that much. if I knew how to get back to the screen to see what I said I would gladly paste it. And I concede that

Comment: My guess would be that the moderator considered the first part of the comment to still be useful: *...there is no native GNU make feature for such problem If you mean prepend to a variable that's not true (at least it's not now in 2019).*

Comment: @BSMP all he says is that he disagrees with the statement that there is no built in feature to do that, which is incorrect else someone would have posted it.. I came here looking for this today there still is not in 2020. You can't prepend recursive expanded vars, only simply expanded ones.  his comment amounts to : your solution is hacky ( which was conceded OP) and I know a built in solution but I'm not sharing it...  I'd be curious what his invisible answer shows but dollars to donuts he does simple expansion `$bar:=$foo $bar`  either way we gain nothing from his comment.

Comment: But you have to be familiar with what's being discussed to know that. To someone who doesn't know anything about makefiles, the disagreement looks like relevant information even if the link no longer works.

Answer (score 4):

"it no longer links to an answer" is not sufficient enough for a Moderator to delete a comment. It is likely, with the amount of comment flags that are cast, especially custom ones, that this did not warrant an investigation from a Moderator.

A no longer needed flag would have been declined as well, as on its face the comment seems proper and topical to the post.

If you are going to use a custom flag message, make sure to *clearly* explain *all* of the contributing factors you observed. In this situation, you left out the fact that the link was to a since deleted answer by the OP due to misunderstanding the situation, and also that the seemingly relevant information in the comment was just a quote from the answer.

For example, you could have flagged it with this message:

> This comment links to a deleted answer (also by the commenter) due to a misunderstanding of the question. The rest is mostly a quote from the answer it was posted to. It is no longer needed.

I believe had you included all of the relevant information, it would have been deleted. However, due to time constraints, without enough information Moderators simply cannot investigate every situation as thoroughly as you do prior to flagging. Going forward, it is prudent if you flag to include all of your observations.

For posterity, and since the linked to post seems relevant and doesn't contain anything negative, here it is:

[image: 10k+ answer]

Comment: For a general user it no longer links to an answer. is that not true?  I deeply question moderation if you think that comment is needed since its entire contents that are true have been updated into the answer.. The OP conceded it was hacky.  So what value does his comment leave?   How do I know the answer was deleted due to misunderstanding I can't read the deleted answer.  At my level of privelage I included all the relevant information I reasonably could.   Perhaps you can demonstrate what I should have said that would have been acceptable.

Comment: @UpAndAdam - I didn't say it was needed, I said that moderators don't have the time to investigate that without a proper amount of detail up front. I did detail what I considered to be sufficient, but I can write an exact suggestion if you think that is more helpful.

Comment: I will say I at least appreciate the much more respectful and helpful tone of your message compared to the comment section.

Comment: I think it would be helpful here. as from my end I had NO way of knowing whether he ever answered it, was pointing to a page that was relocated etc.  And if I reflagged it today I would say "comment solely contains information already conceded and updated into answer, suggestion of an answer with a link that doesn't lead to it for me, and an unsupported statement that there is a builtin feature which no one else seems to have discovered"

Comment: *"due to a misunderstanding of the question"* This would be the clencher.

Comment: Right but how would I have known that when I cant see his deleted answer? @CodyGray ... If I had seen his answer I definitely would have said this.. and I even predicted this answer of his in an above comment thread lol... but I couldn't see the answer until now